# How do I split the date and time into 2 columns using R programming?

Tags: r, date, time, split

The column looks like this:

```
reported_time
3/9/2019 7:07
24/09/2019 08:17:17
3/9/2019 7:27
20/10/2019 08:02:20
2/5/2019 14:15
2/5/2019 14:49
2/5/2019 20:22
20/10/2019 20:42:15
18/09/2019 15:19:20
9/10/2019 9:11
21/10/2019 08:37:05
2/5/2019 8:57
2/5/2019 12:35
2/5/2019 22:46
```

Tried the followings, somehow it doesn't work

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$reported_time)
```

Error in df$reported_time : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

```
df$Time <- format(df$reported_time,"%H:%M:%S")
```

Error in df$reported_time : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

```
data$reported_time <- as.POSIXct(as.character(data$reported_time), format =  "%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

Error in data$reported_time : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Another column by the header name "acknowledged_on" consists of the same date, time format.

Tried the followings, but failed.

Will appreciate advice from anyone. Thank you

```
df$Date <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$acknowledged_on), " "), "[", 1)
```

Error in df$acknowledged_on : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

```
df$Time <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$acknowledged_on), " "), "[", 2)
```

Error in df$acknowledged_on : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

```
df$Date <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$acknowledged_on), " "), "[", 1)]
```

Error: unexpected ']' in "df$Date <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$acknowledged_on), " "), "[", 1)]"

```
df$Time <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$acknowledged_on), " "), "[", 2)]
```

Error: unexpected ']' in "df$Time <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$acknowledged_on), " "), "[", 2)]"

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$acknowledged_on) #already got this one from the answers above
```

Error in df$acknowledged_on : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

```
df$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(df$acknowledged_on) ,format = "%H:%M")
```

Error in df$acknowledged_on : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$acknowledged_on)
```

Error in df$acknowledged_on : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

```
df$Time <- format(df$acknowledged_on,"%H:%M:%S")
```

Error in df$acknowledged_on : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

desired output is (the seconds are removed from the time) :

reported_time
3/9/2019 7:07
24/09/2019 08:17
3/9/2019 7:27
20/10/2019 08:02
2/5/2019 14:15
2/5/2019 14:49
2/5/2019 20:22
20/10/2019 20:42
18/09/2019 15:19
9/10/2019 9:11
21/10/2019 08:37
2/5/2019 8:57
2/5/2019 12:35
2/5/2019 22:46

Comment: You should tag you questions with the language you are using (R) if you want to get answers. I've done that for you.

Comment: I appreciate your many attempts and you were close.  Try this: `data$reported_time <- as.POSIXct( as.character(data$reported_time), format =  "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`.  I would advise against splitting the date and time apart, instead use the `format` function at the time of reporting to control the output.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how is the expected output should look like. Below is my solution:

Assuming you have the time report as a string `s` such as

```
s <- "3/9/2019 7:07 24/09/2019 08:17:17 3/9/2019 7:27 20/10/2019 08:02:20 2/5/2019 14:15 2/5/2019 14:49 2/5/2019 20:22 20/10/2019 20:42:15 18/09/2019 15:19:20 9/10/2019 9:11 21/10/2019 08:37:05 2/5/2019 8:57 2/5/2019 12:35 2/5/2019 22:46"
```

then you can produce a `data.frame` as below, including `Date` and `Time`:

```
v <- gsub("(.*):\\d{2}","\\1",sapply(unlist(regmatches(s,gregexpr("([0-9/]+)(\\s)([0-9:/]+)",s))),function(x) format(as.POSIXct(x,tz="",tryFormats = c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")),USE.NAMES = F))
df <- data.frame(reported_time = v, Date = gsub("([0-9/]+)(\\s.*)","\\1",v), Time = gsub("(.*\\s)([0-9:/]+)","\\2",v))
```

where the output looks like:

```
> df
      reported_time       Date  Time
1  2019-09-03 07:07 2019-09-03 07:07
2  2019-09-24 08:17 2019-09-24 08:17
3  2019-09-03 07:27 2019-09-03 07:27
4  2019-10-20 08:02 2019-10-20 08:02
5  2019-05-02 14:15 2019-05-02 14:15
6  2019-05-02 14:49 2019-05-02 14:49
7  2019-05-02 20:22 2019-05-02 20:22
8  2019-10-20 20:42 2019-10-20 20:42
9  2019-09-18 15:19 2019-09-18 15:19
10 2019-10-09 09:11 2019-10-09 09:11
11 2019-10-21 08:37 2019-10-21 08:37
12 2019-05-02 08:57 2019-05-02 08:57
13 2019-05-02 12:35 2019-05-02 12:35
14 2019-05-02 22:46 2019-05-02 22:46
```

Comment: Hi all, thanks a lot for advise.  However, I still didnt get the format as you guys had

Comment: > data$reported_time <- as.POSIXct( as.character(data$reported_time), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
Error in data$reported_time : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: For this: v <- sapply(unlist(regmatches(s,gregexpr("([0-9/]+)(\\s)([0-9:/]+)",s))),function(x) format(as.POSIXct(x,tz="",tryFormats = c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")),USE.NAMES = F)
df <- data.frame(Date = gsub("([0-9/]+)(\\s.*)","\\1",v), Time = gsub("(.*\\s)([0-9:/]+)","\\2",v))         How do I insert "reported_time" into the it? Thanks

Comment: desired output is  to standardize the date and time format. I need to remove the seconds from the time data as well like this :08:17

reported_time
3/9/2019 7:07
24/09/2019 08:17
3/9/2019 7:27
20/10/2019 08:02
2/5/2019 14:15
2/5/2019 14:49
2/5/2019 20:22
20/10/2019 20:42
18/09/2019 15:19
9/10/2019 9:11
21/10/2019 08:37
2/5/2019 8:57
2/5/2019 12:35
2/5/2019 22:46

Comment: Hi @Newbie101, I updated my solution according to your information, where `reported_time` is inserted as the first column, and the seconds are removed from the data frame `df`